# Data is not getting posted with Sample data API

Tags: javascript, json

Hello everyone I am new to javascript, I am trying to post my data to API.
Here I am attaching my JS code.

I am using [sample data api](https://sampledataapi.com/) to post my data.

```
{"status":"Fail","message":"Required Fields Missing, Please go through API Document"}
```

Here is my js code

```
form.addEventListener("submit", function(e){
    const myData = 'email=sampledatapi@gmail.com&password=202020'
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch("https://sampledataapi.com/API/login", {
        method: 'post',
        headers : {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"} ,
        body: {
            ///
        },
    })
})
```

I have posted my Js code above but its showing error.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch